# How to refactor redundant try catch code?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I am trying to determine the best way to refactor this code. As you can see, the try... catch.. catch.. catch... code lines are identical. The only difference between the two methods is one is async while the other is not.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    try
    {
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        var entityValidationErrors = ex.EntityValidationErrors
            .SelectMany(e => e.ValidationErrors)
            .Select(x => string.Format("{0} - {1}", x.PropertyName, x.ErrorMessage));

        var fullErrorMessage = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, entityValidationErrors);
        var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " Entity validation errors: ", fullErrorMessage);

        throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {                
        var sqlException = ex.GetBaseException() as SqlException;

        if (sqlException == null || sqlException.Errors.Count <= 0) 
            throw;

        var errors = new List<string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < sqlException.Errors.Count; i++)
        {
            errors.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", sqlException.Errors[i].Number, sqlException.Errors[i].Message));
        }

        throw new DbUpdateException(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors));
    }
}
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    try
    {
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        var entityValidationErrors = ex.EntityValidationErrors
            .SelectMany(e => e.ValidationErrors)
            .Select(x => string.Format("{0} - {1}", x.PropertyName, x.ErrorMessage));

        var fullErrorMessage = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, entityValidationErrors);
        var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " Entity validation errors: ", fullErrorMessage);

        throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        throw;
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        var sqlException = ex.GetBaseException() as SqlException;

        if (sqlException == null || sqlException.Errors.Count <= 0)
            throw;

        var errors = new List<string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < sqlException.Errors.Count; i++)
        {
            errors.Add(string.Format("{0} - {1}", sqlException.Errors[i].Number, sqlException.Errors[i].Message));
        }

        throw new DbUpdateException(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `SaveChangesAsync` returns `Task<T>`. That sounds asyncron. The try catch will not catch the same exceptions as the synronous method does. If your async task throws an exception it will not catched using this try...catch. You've to add a continous task that handles the exceptions.

Comment: ... or use async/await

Comment: I updated the post so SaveChangesAsync is async and the base.SaveChangesAsync() is awaitable, but I still don't understand how to get rid of the redundant try/catch/catch/catch code.

Comment: As a general design note, any api should provide either a synchronous or asynchronous implementation. Apis should not provide both sync and async implementations (unless you're constrained by backcompat, e.g.)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing both Sync and Async methods is to have the actual logic in Sync method and the Async method to wrap the first into a Task.

```
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    return new Task(SaveChanges);
}
```

Comment: He has an inherently asynchronous version of the operation, so creating a new thread just to sit there and do nothing while the work is being done *when he already has the tools in place to not do that* is a pretty poor idea.  You're also returning an unstarted Task` here, which is a *really* bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up solving this using a delegate (Func) like so. Here are the two "duplicate" .SaveChanges methods now.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    return SaveChangesWrapper<int>(() => base.SaveChanges());
}
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
{
    return await SaveChangesWrapper<Task<int>>(async () => await base.SaveChangesAsync());
}
```

And here is the wrapper.

```
private T SaveChangesWrapper<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    try
    {
        //do some work up front....

        return function();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        //parse exception and rethrow...
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        //parse and rethrow...
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        //parse and rethrow...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //parse and rethrow..
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `async` method throws an exception in the `try` block then that method doesn't throw, it successfully returns a `Task` (that is in the faulted state).  That's part of what you're "paying for" with the `async` state machine, but as a result, the `catch` blocks will never be hit with the `async` version of this code.

Comment: Well, the easy place to start is by refactoring the body of the `catch` blocks out into separate methods that create the new wrapped exceptions so that they can be called by both of the methods you have.  That gets rid of the worst of the code duplication, even if not all of it.  I don't see a way at first glance to do better than that.

Comment: Not sure you are correct here. I just put a divide by zero exception in the async try block and it gets caught by the last catch, then re-thrown. I see the re-thrown exception in my handler and it propagates back through my web api 2 method to the client as expected.

Comment: Where, exactly, did you put the exception?  Did you put it inside of `SaveChangesAsync`?

Comment: Inside the SaveChangesWrapper.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not where you'll actually have the exception be thrown in practice.  If you put the `throw` in `SaveChangesAsync` then you'd see that when you invoke `function` it doesn't actually throw that exception (it successfully completes, returning a `Task` that is in a faulted state) so your test doesn't suitably simulate an actual problem.

Comment: Ok, I'll do a bit more testing and refactor the catch blocks depending on what I find. Thanks.